# jQuery: what is the n of clicked element

Tags: jquery

So, in jQuery I can find the total number of a type of element with .find('selector').length, but how do I find out what n of the total the element is?

ie: How can I get back the information (n) that I've clicked on the first or second (or nth) button?

eg:

```
<table class="table-edit-components">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link"></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `index()` to get find out what element number you clicked on

```
$( ".add-resource-link" ).index( this );
```

**demo**

```js
$(".add-resource-link").click(function(){
var index = $( ".add-resource-link" ).index( this );
  
  console.log(index)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-edit-components">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link">click</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link">click</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Sanfly no Problem, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index()` to get the position of the `button` you clicked.

```js
$('.add-resource-link').click(function(){
  var nButton = $('.add-resource-link').index(this);
  console.log('Button index is ' + nButton);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-edit-components">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link">1</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link">2</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method of jQuery.

```js
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
  var index = $( "div" ).index( this );
  $( "span" ).text( "That was div index #" + index );
});
```

```css
  div {
    background: yellow;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Click a div!</span>
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>
<div>Third div</div>
```

**In your case it will be something like this.**

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  console.log($('button').index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-edit-components">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link">One</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="resource-links">
                ...
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-resource-link">Two</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does OP has `<ul>`? He asks for button click. You should be using that HTML instead of your own example.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal CarstenLøvboAndersen , it was an example, SO recommends code samples with links to other pages. Since the OP has not given an JS code I gave the sample

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I can't tell you why some people have upvoted this